# Cant close child window that does not have a real URL

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

```
function openwindow() {
   var win = window.open('APP://CALLOUT, 94564584/');
   win.close();
   var win2 = window.open('http://google.com');
   win2.close();
}
```

basically what im trying to achieve is to close the child window "win". but it cant be closed. app://callout is to call my exe.

i tried to use a well formatted url and there was no issue ("win2"). is there anyway i can close my win?

if not, is there a way for me to call this exe? i cant do a file.openread as i need to use web request. response.redirect is ok but it means my button cannot do anything else except response.redirect. i need to do something first with the button before calling the app://callout.

maybe enable a timer to do the response.redirect after the button is click? is this tedious and not efficient?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a workaround already.

not the best, but good enough for me.

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;"><iframe id="if1" runat="server"></div>


Protected Sub btn_submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_submit.Click

   'Do my stuff

    Me.if1.Attributes("src") = "APP://CALLOUT, 94564584" 

    btn_submit_ModalPopupExtender.Show()

End Sub
```